# Can't compile OpenCV 2.4.6 with CUDA 5.5 on Fedora 19

Tags: opencv, build

OpenCV 2.4.6 adds support for CUDA 5.5, but attempts to build it fail. CUDA is installed from the repository for Fedora 18. OpenCV itself without the support of CUDA is also going well.

```
[  1%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/gpumat.cpp.o
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:288:52: error: 'bool cv::gpu::deviceSupports(cv::gpu::FeatureSet)' should have been declared inside 'cv::gpu'
 bool cv::gpu::deviceSupports(FeatureSet feature_set)
                                                    ^
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp: In function 'bool cv::gpu::deviceSupports(cv::gpu::FeatureSet)':
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:288:6: warning: no previous declaration for 'bool cv::gpu::deviceSupports(cv::gpu::FeatureSet)' [-Wmissing-declarations]
 bool cv::gpu::deviceSupports(FeatureSet feature_set)
      ^
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp: At global scope:
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:359:49: error: no 'size_t cv::gpu::DeviceInfo::sharedMemPerBlock() const' member function declared in class 'cv::gpu::DeviceInfo'
 size_t cv::gpu::DeviceInfo::sharedMemPerBlock() const
                                                 ^
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp: In function 'void cv::gpu::createContinuous(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)':
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:794:6: error: redefinition of 'void cv::gpu::createContinuous(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)'
 void cv::gpu::createContinuous(int rows, int cols, int type, GpuMat& m)
      ^
In file included from /home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:44:0:
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/output/include/opencv2/core/gpumat.hpp:551:17: error: 'void cv::gpu::createContinuous(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)' previously defined here
     inline void createContinuous(int rows, int cols, int type, GpuMat& m)
                 ^
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp: In function 'void cv::gpu::ensureSizeIsEnough(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)':
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:806:6: error: redefinition of 'void cv::gpu::ensureSizeIsEnough(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)'
 void cv::gpu::ensureSizeIsEnough(int rows, int cols, int type, GpuMat& m)
      ^
In file included from /home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:44:0:
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/output/include/opencv2/core/gpumat.hpp:559:17: error: 'void cv::gpu::ensureSizeIsEnough(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)' previously defined here
     inline void ensureSizeIsEnough(int rows, int cols, int type, GpuMat& m)
                 ^
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp: In function 'cv::gpu::GpuMat cv::gpu::allocMatFromBuf(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)':
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:831:8: error: redefinition of 'cv::gpu::GpuMat cv::gpu::allocMatFromBuf(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)'
 GpuMat cv::gpu::allocMatFromBuf(int rows, int cols, int type, GpuMat &mat)
        ^
In file included from /home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/3rdparty/opencv/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:44:0:
/home/lucky/programming/sphinx/build/output/include/opencv2/core/gpumat.hpp:567:19: error: 'cv::gpu::GpuMat cv::gpu::allocMatFromBuf(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)' previously defined here
     inline GpuMat allocMatFromBuf(int rows, int cols, int type, GpuMat &mat)
                   ^
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unnamed-type-template-args" [enabled by default]
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/gpumat.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there a way to solve the problem? Or is it a problem too new version of GCC?

Comment: It's a strange error. Maybe it has some problems with header files, e.g. it uses headers from previous OpenCV versions. Do you have any other installed OpenCV versions?

Comment: Yes, locate found a previously installed version of the library, which gave the conflict. Many thanks for the tip.

Comment: @jet47 or Alexander, How about if you post what you did as an answer, so we can call this question closed/answered.  Then I will upvote your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems @jet47 has elected not to respond to my request in the comments, so I'm posting this answer so that we can call this question answered (which it clearly has been in the comments.)

Make sure that you only have one installed OpenCV version, if you experience a problem like this.  If you locate other installed versions besides the one intended, remove them.